# Expand vector to equal steps

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Let's assume I have a vector

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Tjump = c(0.2260760,0.2628534,0.4053514,0.2938391,0.5940260),
                 State = c(9,10,9,8,7))
```

wherein `Tjump` is the elapsed time after which the next state transition occurs. `df` can be plotted as a step function by

```
qplot(cumsum(df$Tjump), df$State, geom = "step")
```

How can I now plot this step function together with another function that runs over `times <- seq(from = 0, to = tail(df$Time, 1), by = 0.01)`?

Or, to approach it differently: how can I expand `df` to have the same amount of entries as `times` by preserving it's step nature?

Comment: Please include any packages that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there is no need to expand the dataframe. You can just add another plot using for example `geom_lines` (or `geom_step` if you want another step function.)

For example as follows:

```
# Note that df$Time does not exist, so I changed it to sum(df$Tjump).
times <- seq(from = 0, to = sum(df$Tjump), by = 0.01)

qplot(cumsum(df$Tjump), df$State, geom = "step") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=times,y=8+runif(length(times),0,1)),colour='red')
```

Output:

[image: Sample plot]

Hope this helps!

Florian

Comment: Yes, it does... would there also be a way to use `ggplot`s `facet_wrap`?

Comment: I do not think that is a good idea, since you want to make two different type of plots. [facet_wrap](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) seems more suited in scenario's where you want the same type of plot for two different subsets of the data. Maybe [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I expand df to have the same amount of entries as times by preserving it's step nature?

This can be done by using `approx` such as:

```
f <- approx(df$Time, df$State, method = 'constant', n = 100)
```